# How can I fix this rotating image issue in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, css-transforms

I have a narwhal that swims around and flips in the direction it's going. When it's clicked, it rotates 360 degrees, then continues swimming. But after rotating, it stops flipping in the direction it's going. How can I fix this?

```js
var $narwhal = $('#narwhalId');
moveNarwhal($narwhal);

function moveNarwhal($narwhal) {
  var myX = Math.floor(Math.random() * ($(window).width() - $narwhal.width()))
  var myY = Math.floor(Math.random() * ($(window).height() - $narwhal.height()))
  if ($narwhal.offset().left < myX) {
    fishFlip($narwhal);
  } else fishFlipBack($narwhal);
  $narwhal.animate({
    top: myY,
    left: myX
  }, 4000, function() {
    moveNarwhal($narwhal);
  }).delay(500);
}

var tmpAnimation = 0;

$($narwhal).click(function() {
  $narwhal.stop(true);
  var element = $narwhal;
  tmpAnimation = tmpAnimation + 360;
  $({
    degrees: tmpAnimation - 360
  }).animate({
    degrees: tmpAnimation
  }, {
    duration: 1000,
    step: function(now) {
      element.css({
        transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)'
      });
    }
  });
  moveNarwhal($narwhal);
});

function fishFlip(IdRef) {
  IdRef.addClass('flipped')
}

function fishFlipBack(IdRef) {
  IdRef.removeClass('flipped')
}
```

```css
.flipped {
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  filter: FlipH;
  -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}

#narwhalId {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="narwhalId" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" />
```

Comment: It works for me. (I've updated the demo snippet to include an image so we can see it working)

Comment: It works but after rotating once, it never flips the image again and I don't know why. It should still flip the image in the direction it's going, but it doesn't do that once it's rotated.

Comment: I suspect that the browser that support both scale and filter will double flip it, so it looks like it didn't flip at all, but that's just an idea

Comment: I don't know if its a browser thing. For me (Chrome, osx) it appears to be fully working and it flips each time the direction changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check for and remove the transform if it exists inline on the element. To make sure the flipped state still keeps, its also advised to check and add the other flipped `transform` as an if into the rotate function

```js
var $narwhal = $('#narwhalId');
moveNarwhal($narwhal);

function moveNarwhal($narwhal) {
  var myX = Math.floor(Math.random() * ($(window).width() - $narwhal.width()))
  var myY = Math.floor(Math.random() * ($(window).height() - $narwhal.height()))
  if ($narwhal.offset().left < myX) {
    fishFlip($narwhal);
  } else fishFlipBack($narwhal);
  $narwhal.animate({
    top: myY,
    left: myX
  }, 4000, function() {
    moveNarwhal($narwhal);
  }).delay(500);
}

var tmpAnimation = 0;

$($narwhal).click(function() {
  $narwhal.stop(true);
  var element = $narwhal;
  tmpAnimation = tmpAnimation + 360;
  $({
    degrees: tmpAnimation - 360
  }).animate({
    degrees: tmpAnimation
  }, {
    duration: 1000,
    step: function(now) {
      if(element.hasClass('flipped')) {
        element.css({
          transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg) scaleX(-1)'
        });
      } else {
        element.css({
          transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)'
        });
      }
    }
  });
  moveNarwhal($narwhal);
});

function fishFlip(IdRef) {
  $narwhal.css('transform','');
  IdRef.addClass('flipped')
}

function fishFlipBack(IdRef) {
  IdRef.removeClass('flipped')
}
```

```css
.flipped {
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  filter: FlipH;
  -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}

#narwhalId {position:absolute;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="narwhalId" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" />
```